# Avoid global variables in my program

Tags: c++, global-variables

I have some global variables in my program and I tried to avoid them but I don't know how..

Here is my program:
[Here](https://github.com/JaouadROS/heightcameraestimation/blob/master/src/subKinect.cpp)

Is there any alternative to avoid those variables?

And any other remark is appriciated too

Comment: encapsulation and instantiation => encapsulate global variable inside a class, as instance member, put function using it as instance member of this class and create an instance inside your main function.

Comment: avoid global variables!!! so, why define them ???

Comment: @MohammadrezaPanahi I meant the way I declared my variables as a global, not the variables themselves

Comment: I don't understand why this question is down voted. ROS_OPENCV realizes that his program technique may not be OK and he wants to improve it. I would understand the down voting when he is *defending* it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have multiple possibilities.

1. Create a class and put your functions and your global variables inside (preferred way)
2. If you just care about name conflicts you can use [unnamed namespaces](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Unnamed_namespaces)
3. It your global variable is used in only one function, declare it as a static variable inside that function (its value will be kept between calls)

Comment: This only preferable way is solution 1. Avoid both other solution with just mask or address some issue about global variables

Answer (score -1):

What about to use a STATIC for i_mouse and depthimagemouse inside the function onMouse (you use it in just 1 function) and a #define for the constant variables? 
I think it can be a good solution in your case.

Comment: `static` implies same problems than global variable: function still not reentrant. You only answer about visibility problems, not about storage duration and reentrance of function. So, if you want avoid global variable, don't use static